I made a clickable image, but it only works once
I'm trying to make a image where you can click it and it will cycle through different images, all on the same image. But even though I get it to work I can only get it to work with one click.


count = 1;

function myFunction(a, b, c) {
  if (count = 1) {
    document.getElementById("johnnycashpicscroll").src = b;
  }
  if (count = 2) {
    document.getElementById("johnnycashpicscroll").src = c;
  }
  if (count = 3) {
    document.getElementById("johnnycashpicscroll").src = a;
  }
  if (count = 3) {
    count = 1;
  }
}
h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 130px;
  left: 120px;
}

#topleftimg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
  top: 100px;
}

hr {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 115px;
}

button {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 60px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 19.5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#button1 {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>

<body>
  <img id="topleftimg" src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.uSeMc9l3nH-tNFb-N2KrrgAAAA?w=155&h=195&c=7&r=0&o=5&pid=1.7" alt="Johnny Cash">
  <h1>Johnny Cash<button id="button1">Home</button><button>Childhood</button><button>Career</button><button>Challenges</button><button>Legacy</button></h1>
  <hr />
  <img src="JohnnyCashPic1.jfif" alt="" height="155" width="100" id="johnnycashpicscroll" onclick='myFunction("JohnnyCashPic2.jfif", "JohnnyCashPic3.jfif", "JohnnyCashPic1.jfif")'>
</body>

</html>



If your curious I'm creating a Johnny Cash informational website for a school project.

You never increment count. So the first if condition will always be true.

Also if (count = 3) is assigning, not testing.  Use == to compare.

You should use == or === for comparison instead of = in your function.


let count = 0;
const images = ["JohnnyCashPic1.jfif", "JohnnyCashPic2.jfif", "JohnnyCashPic3.jfif"];
function myFunction(){
  const imgElement = document.getElementById("johnnycashpicscroll");
  count = (count % images.length) + 1;
  imgElement.src = images[count - 1];
}
<style>
        h1 {
        font-size: 50px;            
        font-family: sans-serif;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 130px;
        left: 120px;
        }
        #topleftimg {
        width: 100px;
        height: 120px;
        top: 100px;
        }
        hr{
        position:relative;
        bottom: 115px;
        }
        button {
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-right: 20px;
        width:120px;
        height:60px;
        font-family:sans-serif;
        font-size:19.5px;
        font-weight: bold;
        }
        #button1 {
        margin-left: 50px;
        }
    </style>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="topleftimg" src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.uSeMc9l3nH-tNFb-N2KrrgAAAA?w=155&h=195&c=7&r=0&o=5&pid=1.7" alt="Johnny Cash">
        <h1>Johnny Cash<button id="button1">Home</button><button>Childhood</button><button>Career</button><button>Challenges</button><button>Legacy</button></h1>
        <hr />
        <img src="JohnnyCashPic1.jfif" alt="" height="155" width="100" id="johnnycashpicscroll" onclick='myFunction()'>
    </body>
    
</html>



Above code should work. Ensure that all images have a valid source to see this in action.
Edit: Thank you for pointing out the mistakes. I have fixed the code and made edits so it runs better. There's no need to pass all the image names to the function. Instead, I used an array in the function with image names and will cycle through the length of the array indefinitely.

It still never increments count.

Please use the 3 separate boxes of the code snippet, instead of putting everything in the HTML box.

Just saw that! Thanks for pointing that out @Barmar! You can either increment the count or cycle though the values (looking at how you have done it in case when count is 3.

This won't work. After you do count = 2, you then do if (count == 2). That's guaranteed to be true, so it will set it to 3, then the next one will be true. You need to use else if so only one condition is triggered.

Or just put count++; after all the if blocks.

I'd be more inclined to use count = count % 3 + 1 assuming OP wants the images to cycle indefinitely

Thank you. I have edited my answer to accommodate your change. I have also used separate boxes for styles, script and HTML.
